# Codesign .app file in Command Line

Tags: macos, cocoa, code-signing, codesign

I am trying to submit the Mac app outside the app store. I take the build from Xcode 4.5 and use the following code for code-signing. But neither of them are working.

```
codesign --force -s  "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: My Company" -v <path to my .app file>

//signed bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64) [com.CompanyNama.AppName]
```

It gives rejected when verifying.

```
codesign --force --sign "Developer ID Application: My Company"  <path to my .app file>
```

It gives rejected, source=No Matching Rule/source=Developer ID when verifying.
I use the following command for verifying,

```
sudo spctl -a -v
```

What I am doing wrong? Which one we should use when code-signing .app file?

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace "Developer ID Application: My Company" with an actual certificate name. Find the production certificate you want to use in Apple's developer portal. Make sure that it's also in your OS X keychain including the private key. Copy the name and replace "Developer ID Application: My Company"

Comment: I have 4 production certificates in the Developer Portal. Mac App Distribution, Mac Installer Distribution, Developer ID Application and Developer ID Installer. Please tell me which one I should use to code-sign .app file?

Comment: "Developer ID Application" is the one the docs say to use. I can't figure out how to create one for my own organisation though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the `source=No Matching Rule` part, but I was getting rejected, because my Gatekeeper was switched to accept "*Mac App store*" apps only. After changing it to "*Mac App store and identified developers*" the check passed.